# How can I upload files to google cloud storage from my server to google's server using PHP to backup my server files?

Tags: php, backup, google-cloud-storage

I have downloaded and installed the google cloud storage PHP library via Composer, downloaded the JSON key file, and I am unable to do anything using the library. I get nothing but errors when i followed the instructions to the letter. Anyway, here is code from the file I am trying to do anything with, like list bucket files, or upload files, etc... Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? I really would like to use the Google Cloud Storage on my server to backup files.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

$gcloud = new ServiceBuilder([
    'keyFilePath' => 'UoNA - Storage-4b777cc06ca3.json',
    'projectId' => 'uona-storage'
]);

function list_objects($bucketName)
{
    //$storage = new StorageClient();
    $storage = $gcloud->storage();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    foreach ($bucket->objects() as $object) {
        printf('Object: %s' . PHP_EOL, $object->name());
    }
}
list_objects('uona-storage-upload');
```

If it helps to clarify, I am using a DreamHost VPS as my server. It supports PHP 7.0. My google cloud storage account is a paid account.

This is the error I am receiving:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function storage() on
>   null in /home/universitytest/uona.today/google/index.php:17 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/universitytest/uona.today/google/index.php(23):
>   list_objects('uona-storage-up...') #1 {main} thrown in
>   /home/universitytest/uona.today/google/index.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that you are missing the following library:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient
```

And the object "StorageClient" is not created.

```
function list_objects($bucketName)
{
    //$storage = new StorageClient();<---- This line
```

Here [1] you have multiple examples for buckets and object in PHP to upload, delete, list and more.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#storage-upload-object-php